# CSS - Want to center LI items in my navbar DIV

Tags: css

I have a navbar on my blog, inside a few divs. I've been tweaking it for 3 hours, but I still can't figure out why the `li` items aren't centered in the middle of the navbar div. Can someone please help? Here's my code:

```
#NavbarMenu {background: #FFF; width: 100%; height: 40px;font-size: 14px; color: #3297FD; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 auto 0; padding:0px; line-height: 20px; text-align : center;}
.navbarleft{width:738px; text-align: center;}

#nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; text-align:center;}
#nav ul { list-style: none; margin: auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; background: #3297FD; }
#nav li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align:center; background: #FFF;}

#nav li a, #nav li a:link, #nav li a:visited {color: #3297FD; display: block; font-family:arial; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 9px 18px 9px; }
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active {background: #2D89E5; color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 9px 18px 9px; text-decoration: none;height: 20px; text-align:center;}

#nav li li a, #nav li li a:link, #nav li li a:visited {background: #3297FD; width: 200px; color: #FFF; font-weight: normal; text-transform: lowercase; float: none; margin: 0; padding: 7px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; border-left: 1px solid #fff; border-right: 0px solid #fff; text-align:center;}
#nav li li a:hover, #nav li li a:active {background:#111; color: #fff; padding: 7px 10px; text-align:center;}

#nav li {float: left; padding: 0; }
#nav li ul {z-index: 0; position: absolute; height: auto; left: -999em; width: 180px; margin-left: 50%; padding: 0; text-align:center;}
#nav li ul a {width: 180px; text-align:center;}
#nav li ul ul {margin: -32px 0 0 171px; text-align:center;}
#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul {left: -999em;}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {text-align:center;}
#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {position: static;
}

#main_navigation {
width: 100%;
margin-auto;
text-align : center;
}

<div id="main_navigation">

<div id='NavbarMenu">

<div class='navbarleft'><center><ul id='nav'>

<li><a href="/">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="/about.me">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/ask">Ask</a></li>
<li><a href="http://twitter.com/ThatsWhatKidsDO">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="/support">Submit</a></li>
<li><a href="/tagged/typography">Typography</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.tumblr.com/directory/recommend/typography/epicjamess">Reccommend</a></li>
<li><a href="/FAQ">FAQ</a></li>

</ul></center></div></div></div></center>
```

Comment: Normal i use float:left but better just replace it with: display:inline-block;text-align:center thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good, clean start:

http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
margin-auto;
```

to

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

You should also not use center tags, as in the latest html releases center tags are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of typos. `<center>` tag is deprecated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    #NavbarMenu {background: #FFF; width: 100%; height: 40px;font-size: 14px; color: #3297FD; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 auto 0; padding:0px; line-height: 20px; text-align : center;}
    .navbarleft{width:738px; text-align: center;margin:0 auto;}

    #nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; text-align:center;}
    #nav ul {list-style:none; margin: auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; background: #3297FD; display: inline-block;}
    #nav li {margin: 0;padding:0;text-align:center;background:#FFF;display:inline-block;}
    #nav li a {display: inline-block;}
    #nav li a, #nav li a:link, #nav li a:visited {color: #3297FD; display: inline-block; font-family:arial; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 9px 18px 9px; }
    #nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active {background: #2D89E5; color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 9px 18px 9px; text-decoration: none;height: 20px; text-align:center;}

    #nav li li a, #nav li li a:link, #nav li li a:visited {background: #3297FD; width: 200px; color: #FFF; font-weight: normal; text-transform: lowercase; float: none; margin: 0; padding: 7px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; border-left: 1px solid #fff; border-right: 0px solid #fff; text-align:center;}
    #nav li li a:hover, #nav li li a:active {background:#111; color: #fff; padding: 7px 10px; text-align:center;}

    #nav li {float: left; padding: 0; }
    #nav li ul {z-index: 0; position: absolute; height: auto; left: -999em; width: 180px; margin-left: 50%; padding: 0; text-align:center;}
    #nav li ul a {width: 180px; text-align:center;}
    #nav li ul ul {margin: -32px 0 0 171px; text-align:center;}
    #nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul ul {left: -999em;}
    #nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {text-align:center;}
    #nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {position: static; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main_navigation">
<div id="NavbarMenu">
<div class="navbarleft">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="/about.me">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/ask">Ask</a></li>
<li><a href="http://twitter.com/ThatsWhatKidsDO">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="/support">Submit</a></li>
<li><a href="/tagged/typography">Typography</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.tumblr.com/directory/recommend/typography/epicjamess">Reccommend</a></li>
<li><a href="/FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This will center them. However you have to many items in the menu to fit them all in `width:738px;` as you specified. You will have to reduce some paddings probably.